# why male penis not considered as cartilage?

Tags: human-anatomy

Penis don't have bone like ears & nose, then why why male penis not considered as cartilage?

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartilage

Comment: Because it's not cartilaginous…

Comment: Welcome to BiologyBeta. Everything is not either cartilage or bone. We have many other tissues. Have a look to [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_(biology)). The penis contain neither bones nor cartilage.

Comment: Btw, Are you sure the `Botany` tag was a good choice? The tag `human-biology` or `anatomy` would be better choices.

Comment: @Remi.b Also see baculum: http://www.mapoflife.org/topics/topic_203_Baculum-%28penile-bone%29-in-mammals/

Comment: If it doesn't have fur like a cow it must be a chicken? ....

Answer (score 8):

feel the tip of your nose. Mush it around, It's got a certain stale gummy bear feeling to it. Now feel your ears, all over. The outer edge, the back, the hard part in the front where the ear meets the face. Feel your adam's apple. This is cartilege.

When you feel your penis, does anything even feel close? Nope. It's just soft. Soft tissue, to be precise.

When stimulated, there are comparmemts within the penis which engorge with blood.

[image]

When they fill up with blood, the penis gets hard. That's all there is to it. No bones, no cartelidge.

If you have any questions, noe's the time to ask.

Comment: +1. And you are telling me I am nice? Answering this question is the nicest thing one could ever do. I deleted two nasty comments to this question.. and left the third :) respect